# I plot these two functions by Matlab but the phase of the both of them look likes strange and I think the plot of the phase is wrong in both of them

Tags: plotting

I plot these two functions by Matlab but the phase of the both of them look likes strange and I think the plot of the phase is  wrong in both of them can you help me to correct these figures
the first function is :
f(z) = (0.10 + 0.3i) + (0.4243 + 0.0017i)*z + (0.9 − 0.001i)*z^2   and its plot is
[image]
the phase of this function look likes wrong because for example at Z_R equales zero Z_I  increace sharply and I do not know the correct value of  Z_I ?
The second function is
f(z) = (0.10 − 0.3i)*z^(−1) + (0.2121 − 0.0008i)*z^(−2) + (0.9 + 0.001i)*z(−3).
and its figure is
[image]

Could anyone help me
1- how to know the phase function is discontinues from the figure?
2- how to plot these functions to get continues phase?

Comment: I'm sorry but you're in the wrong site. This site is for the software _Mathematica_ only. You may consider https://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

"ComplexPlot" does nicely what you want. Note, the absolute value gives the height and the phase the color:

```
f[z_] = (0.10 + 0.3 I) + (0.4243 + 0.0017 I) z + (0.9 \[Minus] 0.001 I) z^2;
ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

[image]
And:

```
f[z_] = (0.10 + 0.3 I)/z + (0.2121 \[Minus] 0.0008 I)/z^2 + (0.9 \[Minus] 0.001 I)/z^3;
ComplexPlot3D[f[z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

[image]